# Defender Preference PowerShell commands differ from corresponding registry keys

Tags: powershell, registry, regedit, windows-defender

I am trying to configure windows defender preferences through PowerShell as administrator. I am using the following commands:

```
Set-MpPreference -ScanScheduleDay 5
Set-MpPreference -ScanScheduleTime 03:57
```

However when checking the results with

```
Get-MpPreference
```

The settings have not changed even after restarting the pc.
However checking the corresponding registry keys (regedit.exe) I find that the keys do change to the new values straight away:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scan
```

Are my commands actually changing the settings? 
Other setting that I can check in the “windows security” app, do work fine such as:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring 1
```

Thanks for any help!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for [`Set-MpPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/set-mppreference?view=win10-ps), it's a little confusing. For the `-ScanScheduleDay` parameter -> Accepted Values, it lists using the word for each day rather than a number. *Try using:*:

```
-ScanScheduleDay Thursday
```

As for the `-ScanScheduleTime` parameter, it says using the number of minutes after midnight to perform the scan. I'm guessing you are wanting the scan to start at 3:57am in the morning so I would *try using*:

```
-ScanScheduleTime 237
```

Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Thanks. However, both using the word Thursday or integer 5 have the same effect of changing the registry key but not the result of Get-MpPreference. Have you tried on your pc? Did it work differently?